# can't set custom data for a QStringListModel

Tags: qt, model-view

I tried to set custom data for a `QStringListModel` using the following code but `setData` always returns false except when the role is `Qt::EditRole` :

```
QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel;
QStringList list ;
list << "str1" << "str2" << "str3";
model->setStringList(list);
QComboBox *box = new QComboBox;
box->setModel(model);
box->show();

qDebug()<<model->index(0);
qDebug()<<model->setData(model->index(0), 1, Qt::UserRole );
qDebug()<<model->data(model->index(0), Qt::UserRole ).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the standard QStringListModel. It has no Qt::UserRole. You have to implement the setData behaviour for Qt::UserRole yourself. To do this you have to subclass QStringListModel and override setData() and data().